# Rotating icosahedron with circles located at every vertex in three.js

Tags: javascript, animation, graphics, three.js, geometry

I have an icosahedron mesh which I am rotating and then adding circle geometries and setting their location to each vertex at every frame in the animation loop.

```
geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(isoRadius, 1);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: wireframeColor,
    wireframe: true
});

isoMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(isoMesh);
```

Set each circle geometries location as the icosahedron mesh rotates:

```
function animate() {

    isoMesh.rotation.x += 0.005;
    isoMesh.rotation.y += 0.002;

    // update vertices
    isoMesh.updateMatrix(); 
    isoMesh.geometry.applyMatrix(isoMesh.matrix);
    isoMesh.rotation.set(0, 0, 0);

    for (var i = 0; i < geometry.vertices.length; i++) {

        nodes[i].position.copy(geometry.vertices[i]);
        nodes[i].lookAt(camera.position);
    }
```

Where var geometry is the geometry of the icosahedron. If I remove the line "isoMesh.rotation.set(0, 0, 0);", the icosahedron rotates correctly, but the rotation of the nodes compounds and spins way too quickly. If I add that line, the nodes rotate correctly, but the icosahedron does not move at all.

I do not understand three.js well enough yet to understand what is happening. Why would adding and removing this affect the nodes' and icosahedron's rotations separately? I believe it has something to do with the difference between the mesh and the geometry since I am using the geometry to position the nodes, but the rotation of the mesh is what shows visually. Any idea what is happening here?

Comment: You are not using three.js as it was intended. Do not update the vertices of your geometry in the animation loop. Perhaps you can learn from [this three.js example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_convex.html).

Comment: Using a group and adding the isocahedron and all the nodes (circles positioned at vertices) worked well, but rotating the group also rotates the nodes. I solved this originally by using looping through the nodes and using lookAt(camera.position), but now it will not work. If I loop through the group and use "iso.children[i].lookAt(camera.position);" the nodes still rotate. Any idea why the use of a group would keep this from working?

Comment: `lookAt()` does not support objects with rotated and/or translated parent(s). Add the nodes to the scene directly, or don't rotate the group, just the icosahedron mesh. Or keep the scene still, and rotate the camera around the scene, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution it multi-layered.

**Your Icosahedron:**

You were half-way there with rotating your icosahedron and its vertices. Rather than applying the rotation to all the vertices (which would actually cause some pretty extreme rotation), apply the rotation to the mesh only. But that doesn't update the vertices, right? Right. More on that in a moment.

**Your Circles:**

You have the right idea of placing them at each vertex, but as WestLangley said, you can't use `lookAt` for objects with rotated/translated parents, so you'll need to add them directly to the scene. Also, if you can't get the new positions of the vertices for the rotated icosahedron, the circles will simply remain in place. So let's get those updated vertices.

**Getting Updated Vertex Positions:**

Like I said above, rotating the mesh updates its transformation matrix, not the vertices. But we can USE that updated transformation matrix to get the updated matrix positions for the circles. `Object3D.localToWorld` allows us to transform a local `THREE.Vector3` (like your icosahedron's vertices) into world coordinates. (Also note that I did a clone of each vertex, because `localToWorld` overwrites the given `THREE.Vector3`).

**Takeaways:**

I've tried to isolate the parts relative to your question into the JavaScript portion of the snippet below.

- Try not to update geometry unless you have to.
- Only use `lookAt` with objects in the world coordinate system
- Use `localToWorld` and `worldToLocal` to transform vectors between
  coordinate systems.

```js
// You already had this part
var geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(10, 1);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: "blue",
    wireframe: true
});

var isoMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(isoMesh);

// Add your circles directly to the scene
var nodes = [];
for(var i = 0, l = geometry.vertices.length; i < l; ++i){
  nodes.push(new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CircleGeometry(1, 32), material));
  scene.add(nodes[nodes.length - 1]);
}

// This is called in render. Get the world positions of the vertices and apply them to the circles.
var tempVector = new THREE.Vector3();
function updateVertices(){
    if(typeof isoMesh !== "undefined" && typeof nodes !== "undefined" && nodes.length === isoMesh.geometry.vertices.length){
    isoMesh.rotation.x += 0.005;
    isoMesh.rotation.y += 0.002;
    for(var i = 0, l = nodes.length; i < l; ++i){
      tempVector.copy(isoMesh.geometry.vertices[i]);
      nodes[i].position.copy(isoMesh.localToWorld(tempVector));
      nodes[i].lookAt(camera.position);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
html *{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#host {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
<div id="host"></div>

<script>
// INITIALIZE
var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
    HEIGHT = window.innerHeight,
    FOV = 35,
    NEAR = 1,
    FAR = 1000;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
document.getElementById('host').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var stats= new Stats();
stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
stats.domElement.style.top = '0';
document.body.appendChild(stats.domElement);


var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(FOV, WIDTH / HEIGHT, NEAR, FAR);
camera.position.z = 50;

var trackballControl = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
trackballControl.rotateSpeed = 5.0; // need to speed it up a little

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, Infinity);
camera.add(light);

scene.add(light);

function render(){
  if(typeof updateVertices !== "undefined"){
    updateVertices();
  }
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  stats.update();
}

function animate(){
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  trackballControl.update();
  render();
}

animate();
</script>
```

Comment: (1) Easier would be `scene.add( camera ); camera.add( light );` (2) Never call `clone()` in tight loops. Think about how many `Vector3`s are you instantiating per second. (3) Instead, add the circles as children of the mesh.

Comment: (1) Good call, I'll edit. (2) I have an idea... I'll edit. (3) Adding the circles to the mesh negates the usefulness of `lookAt` because the mesh is rotating.

Comment: (2) Tried and failed. How do you suggest tracking the positions non-destructively? Calling `isoMesh.localToWorld(isoMesh.geometry.vertices[i])` will change the value of that vertex.

Comment: (2) Create one instance of `Vector3`, reuse it, and use copy(). (3) Yeah, sorry. Could use a `Sprite` instead.

Comment: (2) Good call. Edit made.

Comment: Great this is exactly what I was looking for. Do you know of any resources that will help conceptually understand what localToWorld() does and how it works? Three.js documentation is usually unhelpful. Also do you have any ideas on how to improve performance for smoother animation in this example? My first instinct is to decrease the total amount of vertices, but it seems that the calculations happening here are more expensive than those used in my previous code.

Comment: Picture it like this: Point A is in the scene at (0, 0, 0). Point B is at (5, 0, 0), but its parent is A. If you move A to (5, 0, 0), B's _local_ position remains (5, 0, 0) because that's where it is located relative to A, but B's _world_ position becomes (10, 0, 0), because that's where it is in the scene (world). `localToWorld` uses B's parent (A) to transform B's _local_ position into its _world_ position. In your case, your vertices were all local positions (B) inside your Icosahedron (A), but we needed their world positions to update the circles, which were directly in the scene (world).

Comment: Regarding smoother animation: (1) According to the stats, it's already running at 60FPS. I'm not sure what more you can ask for there... (2) Not sure if it will help, but I would reset your rotation values occasionally. While `icoSphere.rotation.x += 0.005` is a small increment, it will add up over time. I usually track the value by degrees, and reset to 0 when the values hits 360.